# How can I redirect the output of cppcheck into a file?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, stdout, cppcheck

I would like to redirect the output of cppcheck to a text file. It prints a lot of information to *stdout* but if I run `cppcheck --enable=all --verbose . > /srv/samba/share/tmp/cppcheck.out`, I do not get all the information in the file. Why not? How can I get the results in a file?

Comment: You may want to also redirect `stderr`, so try to replace `>` with `>&`

Answer (score 12):

The latest dev version of [cppcheck](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck) contains a new option:

```
--output-file=<file name>
```

Add this option to direct the output into a specific file.

Usage example:

By default cppcheck prints its results to stdout:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all test.cpp 
  Checking test.cpp ...
  [test.cpp:54]: (style) The scope of the variable 'middle' can be reduced.
  (information) Cppcheck cannot find all the include files (use --check-config for details)
```

You can use the option --output-file as follows to store the result in report.txt:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all --output-file=report.txt test.cpp 
Checking test.cpp ...
```

Now the result is stored in report.txt:

```
$ more report.txt 
[test.cpp:54]: (style) The scope of the variable 'middle' can be reduced.
(information) Cppcheck cannot find all the include files (use --check-config for details)
```

As an alternative you could redirect the output to a file:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all test.cpp 2> report.txt
Checking test.cpp ...
```

Now the result is stored in report.txt:

```
$ more report.txt 
[test.cpp:54]: (style) The scope of the variable 'middle' can be reduced.
(information) Cppcheck cannot find all the include files (use --check-config for details)
```